# Length of submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Does there exists a module $M$ of a finite length(greater than $3$) over a ring $R$ such that each submodule of $M$ has different length?(not a simple module)

Let $M$ be a module and $0=M_0\subset M_1 \subset M_2 \subset ......\subset M_n =M$ is chain of submodules of $M$ we say that $n$ is the length of the chain. The length of module $M$ is the largest length of any of its chains.

In order to get such module, what I think is there must be only one such chain exists of largest length in module and all submodules appear in that chain.

I am looking for example of module of length greater than $3$ such that each submodule has different length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and consider the ring $k[x]/(x^3)$. The regular module $k[x]/(x^3)$ has length 3 and contains a unique submodule of length $r$ for $r=0,1,2,3$.

This can be generalized to any $n$, not just $n=3$. A module having a unique composition series is called uniserial. A ring is uniserial if each (finite length) indecomposable module is uniserial. Examples include all (not necessarily commutative) dvrs.

If there is a unique module of each length, then there is a unique simple submodule, each nonzero submodule contains this simple, and by induction on length we see that the module is uniserial.